# Could anyone make me understand what does the code mean in vue.js

Tags: javascript

Could anyone make me understand the below scenario because I tried searching the web and unable to find any info.

I have the below code which does not work because infox is null. But when i change it "`infox: []`" then it works fine. I need to understand why is it so ?

```
data:{
    infox:null
}


 methods: {
      loadmore: function () {
        axios.get(this.url)
this.infox.push(...response.data);
}}
```

Next I want to understand what does the three dot stands for in ...response.data and why I cannot code in the below manner without three dots which makes more sense. I would really appreciate if you could point me to the source.

```
methods: {
      loadmore: function () {
        axios.get(this.url)
this.infox.push(response.data);
}}
```

Below is my JSON data

```
[
  {
    "Categories": "Fashion", 
    "Clicked": 30, 
    "EndDate": "2019-08-21", 
    "HomepageSpotlight": "No", 
    "ImageMainPage": "/static/images/fashion16.jpg", 
    "MainPage": "Yes", 
    "Mainhomepage": "No", 
    "Rating": 5, 
    "SlugTitle": "buy-clothes-with-50-Off", 

  }, 
  {
    "Categories": "Fashion", 
    "Clicked": 145, 
    "EndDate": "2019-08-21", 
    "HomepageSpotlight": "No", 
    "ImageMainPage": "/static/images/fashion10.jpg", 
    "MainPage": "Yes", 
    "Mainhomepage": "No", 
    "SlugTitle": "get-upto-60-off-on-jeans", 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.infox` variable refers to the `infox:null` in your example, so it does not work because `null`, obviously, does not have the method `push`.

When you change the `infox` to an `Array` like `infox: []` then it works because an `Array` does have the method `push`.

**Three dots operator** is a new feature in ES6, you can read about it in a lot of articles, for example here: https://dev.to/sagar/three-dots---in-javascript-26ci

In your case the `this.infox.push(...response.data)` will populate each element of the `data` into the `infox` array. Your `data` is the array it'self, so it will copy the `data` array to the `infox` array.

The `this.infox.push(response.data)` string will result in putting all the `data` array in just one element of the `infox` array.